# Kafka: Database operation with consumer and producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I just started learning Kafka. My requirement is, I have three table Source, Destination and Status. I want to take data from Source table and store it into producer's topic and consumer will consume that data and update the Destination table. Now If data is updated successfully into Destination table,again I want to take data(this time from Destination table) and store it into producer topic and update the third table which is Status.

So far I am able to update the destination table. Due to Consumer keep running I am not able to take data from Destination table and create topic. please any one help how I can do this. I am using Kafka-0.9 with java.

Comment: Use another thread?

Comment: hi, thnx for response, can you please explore how I can use. Sorry I am new in kafka as well as java.